# CompoundTrigger not giving any errors, but values still not being changed?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table summons(Hour, DataJogo, EquipaID, NIF, MinutesPlayed) Where Minutes played are normally 90. However, I have a table(Hour, DataJogo, EquipaID, IF, Minute, TipoAcaoID) And the problem is, if a player has a red card (ActionTypeID(TipoAcaoID) = 8), for example) on the minute 32, the summons table should change the MinutesPlayed to 32.
I changed my approach from using a normal trigger, which was giving me a mutation error, but by using a compound trigger I fixed that error. Now the trigger compiles, but it isn't actually changing values.
I think it's because when I'm doing SELECT COUNT(*) ..., I'm not getting the right values

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_if_red_card_or_two_yellows_before_insert_new_summon
    FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON ACOES COMPOUND TRIGGER
        ContagemAmarelosPKG INT;
        ContagemVermelhosPKG INT;
    BEFORE STATEMENT IS
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ContagemAmarelosPKG
        FROM Acoes 
        WHERE TipoAcaoID = 7;
       
    
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO ContagemVermelhosPKG
        FROM Acoes 
        WHERE TipoAcaoID = 8;
        
    END BEFORE STATEMENT;

    BEFORE EACH ROW IS
    BEGIN

     IF ContagemAmarelosPKG = 2 THEN
        UPDATE CONVOCATORIA
        SET MinutosJogados = (
            SELECT Minuto
            FROM Acoes
            WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 7 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora
        );
            
      ELSIF ContagemVermelhosPKG = 1 THEN
        UPDATE CONVOCATORIA
        SET MinutosJogados = (
            SELECT Minuto
            FROM Acoes 
            WHERE NIF = :NEW.NIF AND TipoAcaoID = 8 AND DataJogo = :NEW.DataJogo AND Hora = :NEW.Hora
        );
    END IF;
    END BEFORE EACH ROW;
END check_if_red_card_or_two_yellows_before_insert_new_summon;
/
```

Comment: Well if you are not getting the right values, did you step through the code in the debugger or put some dbms_output statements to see values?

Comment: Please post the entire setup to reproduce your issue: all the tables involved, some sample data and some inserts